Interaction of Supersonic and Hypersonic Objects
Lets imagine you are chilling in a plane cruising at some Mach 1 or Mach 2. Behind you, parallel with your direction a Mach 11 missile passes you by. What would you experience? Would you experience the Doppler effect?
Would your Mach cone somehow protect you from the missile's Mach cone? Can two Mach cones interfere?
